# How to envision entropy concentration in HKDF "extract" stage?

Tags: entropy, hkdf

[RFC 5869](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869):

> Thus, the goal of the "extract" stage is to "concentrate" the possibly dispersed entropy of the input keying material into a short, but cryptographically strong, pseudorandom key.

The implementation:

```
HKDF-Extract(salt, IKM) -> PRK

PRK = HMAC-Hash(salt, IKM)
```

Here `salt` may be 0. In this case, it feeds `IKM` into HMAC with a fixed key:

```
PRK = H(opad || H(ipad || IKM))
```

How to envision this as a concentration of entropy? How is this different than simply hash the IKM:

```
PRK = H(H(IKM))
```

Or:

```
PRK = H(IKM)
```

Comment: It's not, really, but people seem to like HMAC.  Perhaps a clearer choice would be BLAKE2b(salt=salt, message=IKM).